# SoX merge short audio into long audio in time intervals

Tags: audio, merge, sox

Hi friends I am using SoX command line tool. I am looking for the requirement which a short audio file should be merged multiple times into a long audio file in an interval of fixed time.

short audio should be combined in the long audio file in every 10 seconds till the long audio is completed.

Is there any mix, merge, pad, command example to achieve this. Please help me on this.

Comment: Please help me to decrease the volume for a part of an audio file using gain or any other SoX commands. For example I need to decrease volume for the part starting from 5 seconds to 10 seconds of an audio file and all the remaining part of audio file should be played as same as original.

Comment: this is a different question. I believe it would be better to put a new question with that.

Answer (score 0):

1) create a "repeat-short" with the same duration and repetition
of "short" and silence.

2) final = merge (long, repeat-short)

```
longdur=$(sox --i -d long.wav)

sox short.wav shor-with-silence.wav pad 0 10
sox shor-with-silence.wav shor10.wav  trim 0 10  
sox "|sox shor10.wav -p repeat 1000" repeated-short.wav trim 0 $londdur

sox -m long.wav repeated-short.wav  final.wav
```

(untested, please tell me if it works)